# encryption/decryption of multiple keys

Tags: encryption, aes, des

whether there are adequate ways to make the encryption / decryption of files using several different keys? That is, it is possible to make a group of n keys so that any of the group key could encrypt file and also with any of the group key to decrypt the file? (Of course, provided that no other key, in addition to these n group keys to decrypt the file could not be?)

Comment: Learn about key rotation.

Comment: you can not give the source of where this detail? It is simply the use of a master key for the group and the group of different keys, each of which refers to a master key?

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev If any of the `n` keys could encrypt and decrypt some ciphertext, then you only need 1 key. That's the group key. You could of course generate `n` keys which then use key-wrap to encrypt a single group key. Whether it is what you want, depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming.

Comment: but I need to get all n keys were different, and any other key would not work. for security reasons, I can not conform to store user key and the corresponding group key ...

Comment: If you can encrypt and decrypt with any of the keys, then it doesn't matter if they are identical or not, since they have the same purpose and functionality. If you break one you got them all. You might be better off looking at public key (asymmetric) cryptography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to encrypt with only one key, and be able to decrypt with several other keys individually.

You could have a group key that is encrypted by several keys, so those keys can decrypt the group key as needed, and the group key can be used to encrypt/decrypt data that is shared between users with different keys.

You could do the same thing with the data itself, but this means all keys need to be available for encryption, which doesn't seem to meet your use case.